# string index out of range on generating client lib

Tags: java, macos, google-app-engine

We are developing on Google App Engine. Endpoints developed are working fine locally and in production. Generating client libs using the endpoints.sh works for most of endpoints.

There is only one endpoint that it is not working for some reason. It keeps returning the following:

```
    Error: 500 Internal Server Error
    {"error": {"message": "Internal Server Error", "code": 500, "errors": [{"message": "unknown exception", "debug_info": "string index out of range"}]}}
```

As you can see the error message does not provide much additional information so we've tried running the script in debug mode with no much luck either.

We are developing on OS X, Java 1.7.0_25 and Google App Engine 1.9.40.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as follow. I had an enum for country defined as the country name and its abbreviation. There is one for UNKNOWN and had no abbreviation (its value was actually set to ""). After changing this to "UNKNOWN" it started to work and generate client lib.

Full details on:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13337